# navigationMovement vs moveFocus

Tags: blackberry

I am new to blackberry development.
I would like to know what is the difference between these methods **navigationMovement** and **moveFocus**. when and where it can be used.
For below scenario which one I should use to to get the highlighting functionality  on scrolling over a custom ListView:
I have a custom vertical field manager which contains custom listView(List containing listItem where on focus and unFocus methods overridden to it to highlight the background color of the listItem)

Comment: Care to share some code?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Focus in ListFields is automatic dude, you don't need to override anything. Seems a very strange use case to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

navigationMovement is a lower level UI mechanism than moveFocus.  Navigation movement is called for each trackpad action.  If the navigation movement event is not consumed by any manager or field currently in focus, then the movement is converted into a focus movement, which appears as the moveFocus event.